# show data with angularjs after ajax call

Tags: angularjs

I have a angularjs controller named 'FilterController' in my application . 
It's the controller that the user use to filter some data.
When the user click on Search, I call a Mvc method that return an object with the data. This work well, but the problem is to show the data that i retrive

How can I load this data in a new controller that show this data?

In the model i have this class

```
public class DPIModel
{
    public List<Dpi> listDpi{ get; set; }
}
```

Then the data are contained in a json that have this class
The html is already loaded(because search is an ajax call)
The html is like that

```
<div ng-controller="DPIController">
<div ng-repeat="item in listDpi">
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

name is a property of dpi class

Comment: You can use factory and use it in another controller

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :)

In the script:

```
(function () {
        var app = angular.module("ngHttpApp", []);
    }());


    (function () {
        var order = function ($http) {

            var getOrdershttp = function () {
                return $http.get('api/order')
                  .success(function (result) {
                      return result.data;
                  });
            }
            return {
                getOrdershttp: getOrdershttp
            };
        }
        var app = angular.module("ngHttpApp").factory("order", order);
    }());


    (function () {
        var app = angular.module("ngHttpApp").controller('HttpExampleController', function ($scope, order) {

            order.getOrdershttp().then(function (result) {
                $scope.httporders = result.data;
            });
        });
    }());
```

And in the HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="HttpExampleController">

        <h4>http over controller and factory</h4>
        <p ng-repeat="p in httporders">{{p.OrderId}}</p>

    </div>
```